# Is it possible to get "Instance Name" from the CloudWatch Event Logs in my Lambda Fucntion....?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to get "instance name" in my code from CloudWatch event logs, Is it possible or any other way to do this ...?

Comment: What do you mean by instance name?

Comment: Instance name of mine Ec2 machine in aws which i lauched....!